# PHP string replace for single URL

Tags: php, wordpress, function, preg-match, str-replace

I've been reading various articles and have arrived at some code.

For a single URL on my site http://home.com/example/ (and only that URL - no children) I would like to replace all instances of `"<a itemprop="url"` with just `<a` basically stripping out `itemprop="url"` This is what I have come up with but I'm not sure whether I'm on the right lines and if I am how to 'echo' it on on the basis it's code and not something to be echoed to screen. Also not too sure whether I need to escape the double quotes within the single quotes in `$str_replace`.

```
if(preg_match("%/example/$%", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])){
$string = "<a itemprop=\"url\"";
$str_replace = str_replace('<a itemprop="url"','<a',$string);
//something here
}
```

Please could anyone advise also if I am correct in how I am approaching this what the final part of the code needs to be to run it (I'm assuming not `echo $str_replace;`. I'll be running it as a function from my Wordpress `functions.php` file - I'm comfortable with that if it works.

This could be a mess and I apologise if it is.

Answer (score 0):

try `strpos()`

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "example") !== false){
  $string = "<a itemprop=\"url\"";
  $str_replace = str_replace('<a itemprop="url"','<a',$string);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, having read about `strpos` I don't fully understand but you suggest it would be better than `preg_match` I guess.

Comment: your welcome :) you can accept/upvote helpful answers

Comment: I always do once I have it figured out Rakesh. I'm not sure how it helps yet over the code I had - can you explain the benefit to my situation (just a short sentence)? That would be really helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

There must be some kind of template where you get the default html and modify it with the php at some point of your code...

```
 $html_template = file('...adress_of_the_url_template...');
 .......
 if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "example") !== false){
         $string = "<a itemprop=\"url\"";
         $html_template = str_replace($string,'<a',$html_template);
 }
 .......
 .......
 echo $html_template
```

Then you have replaced the html code as you wanted

Comment: thank you so the server address of the wordpress template used for the url? I can research the structure of creating that root but you mean for example single.php if it were a standard post and that would not be a web URL but an internal server address presumably with forward slashes?

Comment: Yes, review the .php from the begining and try to figure out where it loads the html, that file is where you have to do the replace. If you can't find it, look forward if any other .php includes yours, you may find it there

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I was over-complicating it because the solution appears to be within Wordpress functions. This is what I've ended up with. Any comments, corrections or recommendations appreciated. I'm not a coder as you may realise...

```
function schema( $content ) {
if (is_page( 'my-page-slug')) {
return str_replace('<a itemprop="url"', '<a', $content);
}   
else return $content; 
}
add_filter('the_content', 'schema', 99);
```